# IBM IDAA won't let me query specific column

Tags: db2, websphere

I have an IBM IDAA set up where I created an accelerator-only table with a CREATE statement:

`CREATE TABLE aot_table (
        "col_1" decimal(11,0) NOT NULL ,
        "col_2" smallint,
        "col_3" smallint,
) IN ACCELERATOR my_accel;`

I then loaded it, manually with INSERTS, with test data. When I query it with:

`SELECT * from MY_USER.aot_table;`

I get data as expected.

But if I try querying col_1 directly, like this:

`SELECT col_1 from MY_USER.aot_table;`

I get an error stating:

`select col_1 from MY_USER.aot_table

COL_1 IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.24.92`

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the table with double-quotes around the column names  and lowercase colnames, as shown in your question, then your queries must also double-quote the column-names and match colum-name case.

Otherwise Db2 will fold unquoted column names to uppercase which will not match the lowercase column names, which will result in exceptions.

So try `select "col_1" from MY_USER.aot_table` , assuming that the tabschema is also MY_USER. Notice the quoted column name.

If you do not want to double-quote your column names in your queries then do not use double-quotes around column names in `create table` statement. Unuoted column names in queries will then fold to uppercase which is usually more convenient for SQL.

Comment: Thank you, using double-quotes in the query worked, and based on your comment, I'll be recreating the table without the quotes in the first place.  Thanks again.